# Load css files from node_modules into an Angular component having webpack

Tags: angular, angular7

I have two modules: FrontUI & AdminUI. The FrontUI is the root module and the AdminUI is lazy loaded.

In the Admin section, I need to load few .css files that are different from the FrontUI and is particular to admin section only. I tried the following -

1. I have added these .css file path in angular.json as shown below and this works. But this will bundle these files during startup, which is not proper

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/@xyzPlugIn/base.css",
              "node_modules/@xyzPlugIn/theme.css"
            ],
```

2. I have added the .css file path in component.ts file as follows, but this is not rendering the css

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../node_modules/@xyzPlugIn/base.css',
              '../node_modules/@xyzPlugIn/theme.css']
})
```

Can different styles be loaded for two separate modules, as the client/users are different? In production environment, can these files be bundled?

P.S: The project structure I have mentioned is short for better understanding.

Comment: You can add an import at the top of your component `import '@xyzPlugIn/base.css';`. If you use scss, add `@import "~@xyzPlugIn/base";` to your stylesheet. Also, are your sure your relative path to node_modules is right ?

Comment: I tried with import, @import in component but it doesn't work for .css files. Yes, the relative path is correct in my project.

Comment: @import will be in your stylesheet (without extension and tilde at beginning). import will be in your component (with .css extension). I have used both at several occasions.

Answer (score 21):

Thank you [Jonathan Hamel](/users/5842628/jonathan-hamel).

I achieved by doing the following:

**admin.component.ts**

```
@Component({...
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**admin.component.css**

```
@import "~@xyzPlugIn/base.css";
@import "~@xyzPlugIn/theme.css";
```

1. Adding tilde '~' represents the node_module in Angular.
2. Set encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None so that its sub components can also apply this style.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that `ViewEncapsulation.None` is a bad thing and breaks the principles of component styles.

Comment: If the component is a part of Angular library and I publish it - this path does not work correct, because the css are sought in app root instead of node_modules: `https://localhost:4200/~@xyzPlugIn/base.css`